# Looping over list of dictionaries over a list of dictionaries in a nested loop in ansible playbook

Tags: dictionary, ansible, nested-loops

I need to loop over list of dicts over an another set of list of dicts in a nested loop to read all the values from the output I get. I am new to ansible and tried with with_items, loop, with_subelements and with_nested too. Nothing works for my need to read all the values from the output I have. Can someone shed some light on this how we can do a nested loop? Your help is much appreciated.

```
Outer-List: [    
  { 
     Key1: value1
     Key2: value2          
     Inner-List: [ 
        {
            Key31: value-A
            Key32: value-B
        }
        {
            Key33: value-C
            Key34: value-D
        }
     ],
  },              ====> OuterList[0] ends here
  {               ====> OuterList[1] starts here
     Key1: value1
     Key2: value2
     Inner-List: [       
        {
            Key31: value-E
            Key32: value-F
        }
        {
            Key33: value-G
            Key34: value-H
        }
     ],
   }              ====> OuterList[1] ends here
]                 ====> OuterList ends here
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Loop over list of dicts.*"**

A: Given a valid [YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/) and valid [Ansible variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names)

```yaml
Outer_List:
  - Inner-List: 
      - Key31: value-A
        Key32: value-B
      - Key33: value-C
        Key34: value-D
    Key1: value1
    Key2: value2
  - Inner-List: 
      - Key31: value-E
        Key32: value-F
      - Key33: value-G
        Key34: value-H
    Key1: value1
    Key2: value2
```

Use [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries). For example, the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.Key1 }} {{ item.0.Key2 }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ Outer_List }}"
        - Inner-List
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'value1 value2 {''Key31'': ''value-A'', ''Key32'': ''value-B''}'
  msg: 'value1 value2 {''Key33'': ''value-C'', ''Key34'': ''value-D''}'
  msg: 'value1 value2 {''Key31'': ''value-E'', ''Key32'': ''value-F''}'
  msg: 'value1 value2 {''Key33'': ''value-G'', ''Key34'': ''value-H''}'
```

---

Below is valid [JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) if needed

```yaml
{
"Outer_List":
    [
        {
            "Inner-List": [
                {
                    "Key31": "value-A",
                    "Key32": "value-B"
                },
                {
                    "Key33": "value-C",
                    "Key34": "value-D"
                }
            ],
            "Key1": "value1",
            "Key2": "value2"
        },
        {
            "Inner-List": [
                {
                    "Key31": "value-E",
                    "Key32": "value-F"
                },
                {
                    "Key33": "value-G",
                    "Key34": "value-H"
                }
            ],
            "Key1": "value1",
            "Key2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```